# Program In Background Javascript

Tags: javascript, background

Say I make a program and run it on chrome, then switch tabs.

Or what if I open my javascript app, then switch apps, while having mine in the background.

Is there way to tell if the program is on foreground or background in javascript?

Thanks, this would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Page Visibility API to handle foreground/background switch in Javascript.

```
if (document.visibilityState == "visible") {
    // foreground
} else if (document.visibilityState == "hidden" {
    // background
}
```

Checking for document.hasFocus() wouldn't work on cases when the page is running in foreground (and visible), but not focused.

Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`document.hasFocus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus) to check if the current page is focused.